# How to test the angular service worker

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm registering my angular service worker (from @angular/PWA) in `app.component.ts`. I'm unable to determine how to register `ngsw-worker.js` in `app.component.spec.ts`. It's in the dist folder, as part of a production build (only available with --prod). My import in the test file looks like this:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: true }),
```

The error message:
`Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:<port>/') with script ('http://localhost:<port>/ngsw-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`

It doesn't look like `ng test` includes a `--prod` option

As it's the `ngsw-worker`, it uses `this.scope.skipWaiting()` during install and `yield this.scope.clients.claim()` during activate, so it seems as though registering the sw correctly in a unit test should do the trick.

I've looked through the localhost directory in devtools but I'm not seeing the sw anywhere.

Question: In light of the above, how can I register the ngsw-worker.js for testing purposes?

Answer (score 4):

To be a bit more precise,

You have to first download [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) which is a "simple, zero-configuration command-line http server".

1. Install http server on your laptop globally `npm install --global http-server`
2. Build your project locally `ng build --prod`
3. run http-server `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<project-name>` *-c-1 = disable caching*
4. Then open your browser in incognito mode with this url `http://localhost:8080/`

For more information about it : https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#serving-with-http-server

Comment: I find this unusable because in order to run tests or even check my code changes I need to continuously and manually re-build my code and re-run the server. Is there any way to get it to automatically update such as with a "--watch" flag?

Answer (score 0):

first build production and then run

```
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/your-projectname
```

and open incognito tab and go to

```
localhost:8080
```

and test your service worker